# I want to send a notice without crashing

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

### Question

I refer to the following page and I am sending a non-fatal log on Unity's C #
I can not confirm the notification on the dashboard.

Could you tell us the problem?

Also, if you know how to notify the log without crashing please let me know.

### My Test Source code

```
public static void SendCrashMessagePlusCustomStackTrace (string name, string reason, string stackTraceString)
{
    Crashlytics.RecordCustomException (name, reason, stackTraceString);
    Crashlytics.ThrowNonFatal ();
}
```

### Reference page

https://docs.fabric.io/unity/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html

### Development environment

Unity 5.6.3 p1

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Make you sure you change the filter on the Fabric dashboard from Crashes to Non-Fatal or All Events.

Comment: We have already changed to dashboard and checked, but we will not notice and the display will not change.Is there anything to check on the Unity side?

Comment: Unity C# runtime exceptions rarely result in a crash which is why I saying you should switch to the non-fatal view. You're throwing another one which should be present, so I'd need to see your app's bundle id or package name to dig in more. If you don't feel comfortable sharing it publicly, please email support(at)fabric(dot)io and reference this thread.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, we will send bundle ID and application name to Fabric via e-mail.
I am thinking of clarifying the cause of this problem.